# Include Null values in Search Result

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have written following Query for Elasticsearch which works as expected

```
es = self.get_elastic_search_instance()
            s = Search(using=es, index="school", doc_type = "student") \
                .filter("term" , studentId = student_ID ) \
                .filter("term" , isPremium = premium_search ) \
                .filter("geo_bounding_box", location = { "top_right" : {"lat": x2, "lon": y2   },
                      "bottom_left" : { "lat": x1,  "lon": y1 }}) \
        .query("range", termFees = { "from": min_fee, "to": max_fee })

            if course_query:
                s = s.filter ("terms" ,courseId = [1302 , 1303 ] )
```

I would like to add two constraints

1. Include "null" value for "termFees"
2. Include "null" value for courseId

How to include them, I tried with few options it didnt work.

Comment: You cannot search for `null` in Elasticsearch. Is your intention to match those documents even if the field `termFees` or `courseId` do not exist in those documents?

Comment: courseId do not exist in those document.

Comment: Have you tried the [`missing` query/filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-missing-query.html)?

Comment: I dont know how to include missing field in "s = s.filter ("terms" ,courseId = [1302 , 1303 ] )"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write multiple `should filters` like this, `|` is **OR**(should) operator

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search, Q, F <--- Import F(for Filters)

s = s.filter(F('terms', courseId = [1302 , 1303 ]) | 
             F('missing', field='courseId') |
             F('missing' , field='termFees'))

print s.to_dict() <--- it will print JSON query, very helpful
```

Hope this helps!!